# Get input element inside <tr> with based on data-attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code:

```
<tr class="my-field" data-name="background_colour" data-type="color_picker">
    <td class="my-input">
        <div class="my-color_picker">
              <input type="text" class="wp-color-picker">
    </td>
</tr>
```

I need to get that input text element with  `class="wp-color-picker"`.

I can do this with `$('input.wp-color-picker')`, but that will get all input elements with `class=wp-color-picker`. I only want to get those elements that are inside a `tr` with `data-name='background_colour'`.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) to combine those to needs

```
$('tr[data-name="background_colour"] input.wp-color-picker')
```

Here `tr[data-name="background_colour"]` will find the `tr` you are looking for then the descendant selector along with the `input` selector(`input.wp-color-picker`) will find the target element.

- [Attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)
- [Descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

`$('tr[data-name="background_colour"] input.wp-color-picker')`

Example:

```js
alert($('tr[data-name="background_colour"] input.wp-color-picker').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr class="my-field" data-name="background_colour" data-type="color_picker">
    <td class="my-input">
        <div class="my-color_picker">
              <input type="text" class="wp-color-picker" value="hello world">
    </td>
</tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("tr[data-name='background_colour'] .wp-color-picker")
```